# Sockets in C: read() returns > 0 bytes read, but buffer is zero

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to read data from a socket in C. There will be two messages.

I am trying to send the size of the message to the socket so that the read() command will know when the message ends and can stop reading at that point. Otherwise, it will read both messages into one blob. The problem is that the read command sets the buffer to 0 even though it read > 0 bytes.

Here is the code:

```
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(int)); 
     int bytes_to_read = atoi(buffer); 
     fprintf(stdout, "Here is the size of the data to look for: %d", bytes_to_read);
     /*read message*/
     fprintf(stdout, "Reading first message.\n");
     int bytesread = 0;
     int chunk = bytes_to_read > 255 ? 255 : bytes_to_read;  
     do {
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(newsockfd,buffer,chunk);
        bytes_read += n; 
        fprintf(stdout, "The value of n is %d and here is the new buffer after the first read: %s and new buffer length is : %d\n", n, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        strcat(plaintext, buffer); 
        size += 256;
        plaintext = realloc(plaintext, size); 
     } while (bytes_read < bytes_to_read);
```

The output I get shows that n = 36 (as expected) but buffer is 0 and the length of buffer is 1.

Why would the read() command be setting the buffer to 0? Is there an easier way to tell read() where to stop reading?

EDIT: 
Based on the feedback I got, I drastically re-wrote this. Note that I know the client will send one packet containing the number of bytes in the data as a unit32_t, then it will send the data.

```
char * readText(int newsockfd) {
char * text = malloc(256); 
char buffer[256];
int n; 
int size = 256;
/*find out how many bytes are in the data*/
 uint32_t bytes_to_read; 
 n = read(newsockfd, &bytes_to_read, sizeof(uint32_t)); 
 bytes_to_read = ntohl(bytes_to_read); 

 /*read data from client*/
 int bytes_read = 0;
 int bytes_left = bytes_to_read; 
 /*the maximum we can read at one time is 255 bytes since that is the size of the buffer. 
 * the buffer could have been larger but we'd still have to check the data size and keep calling
 * read() until we get all of the data. 
 * If the data to read is smaller than the buffer, then we just read it in one go. If the data is larger, 
 * then we read it in 255 byte-sized chunks until we have read all of it*/ 
 int chunk = (bytes_to_read > 255) ? 255 : bytes_to_read;
 do {
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,chunk);
    /*copy over the data we have read so far into the text buffer
    We offset by the amount we have already read in so we do not overwrite the data already 
    in the array*/
    memcpy(text + bytes_read, buffer, n);
    bytes_read += n; 
    bytes_left -= n; 
    /*if we have less than 255 bytes left, just read that amount. This prevents read() from pulling in too much data and messing up the next read() call*/ 
chunk = (bytes_left > 255) ? 255 : bytes_left;
    size += n;
    /*grow the text variable by as much as we just read in. This makes room for 
    the next chunk of data. The next chunk could be as large as 255 bytes*/ 
    text = realloc(text, size); 
 } while (bytes_read < bytes_to_read); 
 text[bytes_read] = '\0'; //null terminate our string so we can use string functions on it. 
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
return text; }`
```

Comment: `buffer` is a pointer to a buffer (or maybe the buffer itself, if it's declared as an array), and the length of it is however many bytes you allocated. This does not change.

Comment: 1) when reading from a socket, should use 'recv()' , not 'read()'  2) read/recv does not terminate the read in data.  so the code has to specifically do that.  3) before the first call to strcat(), the first byte of the 'plaintext[]' must be '\0'  4) strlen(buffer) could be anything because the read string has not been terminated,  5) when using realloc() always check(!=NULL) the returned value before assigning it to the target pointer,

Comment: continuing:  6) the first call to read() is expecting 4 ascii characters (sizeof(int)).  which may or may not be correct.  if only 3 characters transmitted,  the function will hang forever, 7) there are several other problems in the posted code

Comment: regarding this line: 'int chunk = bytes_to_read > 255 ? 255 : bytes_to_read;' this line can fail due to presidence of the C operators.  suggest: 'int chunk = (bytes_to_read > 255) ? 255 : bytes_to_read;'

Comment: @user3629249 No it can't. All you've done there is introduce redundant parentheses. And there is no 'can fail' about it. Either the precedence is correct, so it can't fail, or it isn't correct, so it *will* fail. The precedence *is* correct and so this *cannot* fail. No indeterminacy there.

Answer (score 3):

1. There's no guarantee you received the entire length message.
2. You're reading it for `sizeof int` bytes, which suggests binary data, but you're then calling `atoi()`, which suggests null-terminated ASCII data in the form of a decimal string. Which is it?
3. If you're getting a return value of 36 that's how many bytes were received, and if the buffer contains `{0, 1}` that's what was received too.
4. It simply isn't valid to just use `strlen()` or `strcat()` on an arbitrary array of bytes. These functions are for null-terminated strings. There is nothing about TCP that says every buffer you receive will be a null-terminated string, and nothing that says what you receive will even be printable.

What you're doing is simply not valid.

Comment: OP: True, and the only information you have about how many bytes were recieved, is the return value of `read()`.

Comment: Ok I'm completely lost then. I don't want to ask too broad of a question, but is there a tutorial somewhere for this kind of thing?

Comment: I do not know of any tutorial that covers all the details.  What is being stated is from the 'hard' hand of experience.